# "Match the answer" is the verb "match" natural in this context

Tags: word-usage, verbs, spoken-english

Many math books  are  published with *answer key to the exercises.*

Can I say:

> After solving the math problems you should **match the answers** to see if you have get them correct.

Is the verb **match** is suitable to use in this context?

How would English speakers say this?

Answer (score 1):

"Match" is acceptable in this context although the far more common verb in the U.S. is "check." Your sentence, however, is not highly idiomatic in other respects.

> After solving the problems, match your answers with those in the answer key to ensure that your answers are correct

is pefectly acceptable, but much less frequent than would be

> After solving the problems, check your answers against those in the answer key to ensure that your answers are correct

In general, however, the verb "match" would not be used if you confirmed by doing something more logically demanding than using an answer ley. In those cases, the verbs used would usually be "check," "verify," "validate," or "confirm" rather than "match," which simply means verifying that two items are the same.